# mysql load data infile system lock state

Tags: mysql, locking

in mysql is there a way to "load data infile" without locking or checking for table locks?
I have other processes reading the same table, I want to perform a "load data infile" into this table.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is InnoDB (which supports row-level locking) and if the table is properly indexed, concurrent reads on pre-existing rows should be possible by default.

If the table is MyISAM, then the [`CONCURRENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) option might help:

> If you specify `CONCURRENT` with a MyISAM table that satisfies the condition for concurrent inserts (that is, it contains no free blocks in the middle), other threads can retrieve data from the table while `LOAD DATA` is executing.

If none of the above works, then you can split your input file in smaller parts and load each part successively. This way, concurrent (blocked) reads would be processed between each batch, reducing their waiting time. But with this option, you need to take address data integrity questions (namely: should concurrent reads be allowed to access partially loaded data before the entire bulk loading operation is complete?)